# Does sequence of clustering keys matter when querying in YugabyteDB YCQL

Tags: yugabytedb

[Question posted by a user on [YugabyteDB Community Slack](https://www.yugabyte.com/slack)]

I have a question regarding clustering column order in YCQL. Below is the PRIMARY key definition:

```
 PRIMARY KEY (fsym_id, item, fiscalperiodenddate, startdate)
) WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY (item ASC, fiscalperiodenddate DESC, startdate DESC).
```

Does sequence of clustering key matter when they try to query? For example:

```
select * from factsetestimatev4.con_af where fsym_id = 'Q2YN1N-R' and item='EPS' and startdate<='2022-05-03' and enddate>='2022-05-03' and fiscalperiodenddate>='2022-12-31';
```

VS

```
select * from factsetestimatev4.con_af where fsym_id = 'Q2YN1N-R' and item='EPS' and fiscalperiodenddate>='2022-12-31' and startdate<='2022-04-04' and enddate>='2022-04-04';
```

As per my understanding, it should not matter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The order of predicates in the query doesn't matter.  The examples below are the same:

```
WHERE cond1 and cond2
```

Vs

```
WHERE cond2 and cond1
```

But a good choice of PRIMARY KEY matters independent of the above point.

Alo, `enddate` is not part of PK.. so the app could have some inefficiency there because it might have to scan everything that's `startdate < Apr/04th..` for the provided `fsym_id, item, fiscalperiodenddate`.